What is a perfect example for the sentence "There is a sequence point immediately before a library function returns" in C11 standard?
As is well known, the sentence:

There is a sequence point immediately before a library function returns.

which comes from 7.1.4 p3 in the C11.
I have also seen in some posts some explanations of this sentence from some experts.
For example, in this post, I learned:

Library functions don't have the code that implements them covered by the standard (they might not even be implemented in C). The standard only specifies their behaviour. So the provision about return statements does not apply to implementation of library functions.

And in this post, I found the example someone gave for this sentence, which is:

t = sqrt(t);


The author of this post says that without this sentence, this piece of code would lead to undefined behavior (I'm just simply repeating the original text).
Actually, I don't understand why this is the case.
I found in the C11 standard these about the behavior will lead to undefined:
6.5p2:

If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar
object, the behavior is undefined. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the
subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an unsequenced side
effect occurs in any of the orderings.

But for this example, after the lvalue conversion, the library function sqrt() is operating on just a copy of a value. I think none of the above applies (just my thought).
Then, why is it an undefined behavior?
Or, if it is wrong and my analysis is correct, is it possible to give a perfect example that fits this sentence?
Just looking at this sentence in the standard is too abstract for me. I hope to have an example to help me better understand this sentence.

@mkrieger1:Oh, of course, I hope to see an example.

The second post is an over-simplification. In case of  t = sqrt(t) there are at least two sequence points guaranteed. It goes as: evaluation of argument t, sequence point, function call, (any number of sequence points), sequence point, function return, assignment to t.

@Lundin:Just analyzing this piece of code, you are correct. But I don't think it is a very good example to prove the importance of that sentence.

The answer in the question you link to is wrong. t = sqrt(t); would not have undefined behavior if there were no sequence point before the function return. C 2018 6.5.16 3 says, about assignment, “… The side effect of updating the stored value of the left operand is sequenced after the value computations of the left and right operands…” So even if sqrt were implemented as a macro with no sequence points at all, the behavior would not be undefined.

Defect Report #147 uses this as an example: #include <string.h> char s[10]; /* ... */ (strcpy)(s, "Testing") [0] = 'X';. There needs to be a sequence point before the call to strcpy returns, otherwise s[0] would be modified twice between sequence points.

@IanAbbott That DR is kind of a bleak argument though - the problem described is only a symptom that arises because strcpy has such a bad API, returning a pointer when there's no need for it - which is the root cause of the problem. Had it been designed properly as void strcpy then there wouldn't have been any issues because you'd be forced to call it in multiple expressions separated by a ;.


t = sqrt(t);

The author of this post says that without this sentence, this piece of
code would lead to undefined behavior

The author doesn't say that in so many words.  To the extent that they imply it, however, they are wrong.

Actually, I don't understand why this is the case. I found in the C11
standard these about the behavior will lead to undefined:
6.5p2:

If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either
a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value
computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is
undefined.


I think that must be the section that inspired the claim you are asking about, but it is not in fact relevant to the analysis of the definedness of the behavior of t = sqrt(t).

But for this example, after the lvalue conversion, the library
function sqrt() is operating on just a copy of a value. I think none
of the above applies (just my thought).

That's not what saves the example, but see below.
The potential issue here is that there is a read of t as part of its lvalue conversion, and there is a side effect on the value of t from evaluating the assignment.  (You may not think of the assignment's effect of updating the value of t as a "side effect", but formally, that's what it is.)  If these were unsequenced with respect to each other then the behavior would be undefined, per the provision you quoted.
There being a sequence point immediately prior to the return of the sqrt() call is neither necessary nor sufficient to rescue that situation:

It is not necessary because

There is a sequence point after the evaluations of the function designator and the actual arguments but before the actual call.

(C11 6.5.2.2/10)
If a sequence point immediately prior to the return were sufficient to prevent the UB in question, then this earlier sequence point would also be sufficient.  This is basically equivalent to your argument about lvalue conversion happening before the function call.

It is not sufficient (and neither is paragraph 6.5.2.2/10 alone), because it does not establish sequencing with respect to the side effect of the assignment.  No doubt you will think "of course the value being assigned needs to be determined before t's value can be updated," and you will be right.  This is the main thing that saves t = sqrt(t) from having UB according to paragraph 6.5/2, and it is expressed formally in paragraph 6.5.16/3, about assignment expressions:

The side effect of updating the stored value of the left operand is sequenced after the value computations of the left and right operands.

The combination of that with paragraph 6.5.2.2/10 (see above) establishes the needed sequencing, and you do not get it without both of those, so paragraph 7.1.4/3 is not relevant to this analysis.



is it possible to give a perfect example that fits this sentence?

What's needed is a situation where there is

a side effect on the value of some object t (typically a write to that object),
either a read of that object or another side effect on its value, and
one of those is part of the defined behavior of a standard library function, and the other happens after that function returns, before the next sequence point or anything else creating a relevant sequencing relationship.

The sqrt example does not satisfy because there is no access to object t during the execution of that function.  In order for the required scenario to occur, we need a function that either accesses an object with static storage duration (a external variable, say, or a static one) or accesses some object via a pointer received as an argument. The most likely function candidates are thus those that accept pointer arguments and operate on the pointed-to object.  The string functions and stdio functions seem the most fertile ground.
We also need another access to the same object that is not sequenced with respect to the execution of the function by any other means. This requirement is the trickier one, because there are a lot of things that have sequencing implications.  In addition to the ones already mentioned, there is this from paragraph 6.5/1:

The value computations of the operands of an operator are sequenced before the value computation of the result of the operator.

... plus the sequencing effects of the ,, &&, ||, and ?: operators on the evaluations of their operands, and the sequence point at the end of each complete statement.
Since for this purpose we cannot span multiple statements, we need a call to the function to appear as an operand in an expression where the call and the larger expression produce separate, conflicting accesses to the same object.  The most plausible examples I can think of are expressions where the return value of strcpy, strncpy, strcat, strncat, memcpy, or memmove is used to access the destination string or object.  For example,
// composing string operations
strcat(strcpy(url, "https://"), "stackoverflow.com/");

I think there are other kinds of expressions that would have the same issue, too.


There is a sequence point immediately before a library function returns.

This is mainly there to ensure the proper behavior of library functions implemented as function-like macros, which is allowed for a whole lot of library functions. Without the guarantee, such macros could resolve in ways that aren't sequenced, or resolve in multiple evaluations etc.
The C standard actually addresses this somewhat well for anyone who can read the wall of text found at C17 7.1.4 §1, just before the parts you quoted. Quoted below: SIC - kindly don't blame me for the horrible formatting. Bold emphasis is mine to point out some particularly important parts:

Each of the following statements applies unless explicitly stated otherwise in the detailed descriptions
that follow: If an argument to a function has an invalid value (such as a value outside the
domain of the function, or a pointer outside the address space of the program, or a null pointer, or a
pointer to non-modifiable storage when the corresponding parameter is not const-qualified) or a type (after promotion) not expected by a function with variable number of arguments, the behavior
is undefined. If a function argument is described as being an array, the pointer actually passed
to the function shall have a value such that all address computations and accesses to objects (that
would be valid if the pointer did point to the first element of such an array) are in fact valid. Any
function declared in a header may be additionally implemented as a function-like macro defined
in the header, so if a library function is declared explicitly when its header is included, one of the
techniques shown below can be used to ensure the declaration is not affected by such a macro. Any
macro definition of a function can be suppressed locally by enclosing the name of the function in
parentheses, because the name is then not followed by the left parenthesis that indicates expansion of
a macro function name. For the same syntactic reason, it is permitted to take the address of a library
function even if it is also defined as a macro.189) The use of #undef to remove any macro definition
will also ensure that an actual function is referred to. Any invocation of a library function that is
implemented as a macro shall expand to code that evaluates each of its arguments exactly once,
fully protected by parentheses where necessary, so it is generally safe to use arbitrary expressions as
arguments. 190) Likewise, those function-like macros described in the following subclauses may be
invoked in an expression anywhere a function with a compatible return type could be called.191) All
object-like macros listed as expanding to integer constant expressions shall additionally be suitable
for use in #if preprocessing directives.

And this would be the main reason why 7.1.4 §3 "There is a sequence point immediately before a library function returns" exists.

Now we should also note C17 6.5.2.2 §10 stating the presence of another highly relevant sequence point:

There is a sequence point after the evaluations of the function designator and the actual arguments
but before the actual call.



The author of this post says that without this sentence, this piece of code would lead to undefined behavior (I'm just simply repeating the original text).

Probably not? Without any or both of the sequence points mentioned above, t = sqrt(t) could perhaps invoke UB, but I don't quite see how.
Without the "sequence point before returning", then if sqrt was implemented as a function, we are dealing with a copy of t and there is no problem with sequencing in t = copy_of_t;. But if sqrt was implemented as a macro, the result is likely the same t as we passed, and then we might get UB in some oddball caller scenario like ++t + sqrt(t) (which is already UB even before the function call) but probably not in case of t = sqrt(t). I don't see why sqrt implemented as a macro would modify t and cause a side-effect, which is the only way that it would invoke UB in this case.

Lets come up with some simpler example - suppose we are to implement abs and as a function-like macro. One very naive implementation would be this:
#define abs(expr) ( expr * ((expr>=0) - (expr<0)) )

That is:

In case of positive value, multiply the expression with (1 - 0) = 1,
otherwise multiply the expression with (0 - 1) = -1.

There's lots of problems with this macro but for now lets just note that contains no sequence points.
Without the rules in 7.1.4 this would lead to multiple evaluations and no sequence points. Now suppose the caller code looks like this:
x = abs(++x);

That will expand to:
x = (++x * ((++x>=0) - (++x<0)) );

Which is wildly undefined behavior since there's multiple side-effects and value computations not sequenced in relation to each other.
This macro wouldn't be conforming to 7.1.4 so the library author will have to reconsider what they are even doing here.

NMDV, but I do take the question to be about what programs depend 7.1.4/3, and why, whereas this answer focuses on that provision's constraints on C implementations.
